# element address in 3 dimensional array

Tags: arrays, data-structures

I am looking for the formulas to find the memory location of an element in a 3-D Array for row major and for column major. After using my logic I end up with the following formulas.
say array is `A[L][M][N]`.

row-major:`Loc(A[i][j][k])=base+w(M*N(i-x)+N*(j-y)+(k-z))`
column-major:`Loc(A[i][j][k])=base+w(M*n(i-x)+M*(k-z)+(j-y))`

where x, y, z are lower bounds of 1st(L) 2nd(M) and 3rd(N) index.
I tried this formula and got the correct result but when I applied this formula on a Question in the book then the answer did not match. Please can anyone help me out with this.

Comment: Please refer to : https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/memory-layout-of-multi-dimensional-arrays to get the correct and clear understanding of multi dimensional arrays, row and column major representations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Formula for 3D Array

#### Row Major Order:

Address of

```
A[I, J, K] = B + W * [(D - Do)*RC + (I - Ro)*C + (J - Co)]
```

#### Column Major Order:

Address of

```
A[I, J, K] = B + W * [(D - Do)*RC + (I - Ro) + (J - Co)*R]
```

Where:

- B = Base Address (start address)
- W = Weight (storage size of one element stored in the array)
- R = Row (total number of rows)
- C = Column (total number of columns)
- D = Width (total number of cells depth-wise)
- R<sub>o</sub> = Lower Bound of Row
- C<sub>o</sub> = Lower Bound of Column
- D<sub>o</sub> = Lower Bound of Width

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 3):

Right one is:

```
row-major:Loc(A[i][j][k])=base+w(N*(i-x)+(j-y)+M*N(k-z))
column-major:Loc(A[i][j][k])=base+w((i-x)+M*N(k-z)+M*(j-y))
```

Comment: I think formula for column major would be `base +  w((i-x) + L*(j-y) + L*M*(k-z))`. Or am I wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks! [@Vinay Yadav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9042318/vinay-yadav) for your comment. As suggested by *Vinay* please visit the link to understand this in great detail: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/memory-layout-of-multi-dimensional-arrays.

Keep this in mind and you never get it wrong:
Row Major: **Lexicographical Order**
Column Major: **Co-lexicographical Order**

If you don't know what **Co-lexicographical** and **Lexicographical** are: Check out [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) Wikipedia page for more. Let me highlight important part for you, do give it a read:

> The words in a lexicon (the set of words used in some language) have a
> conventional ordering, used in dictionaries and encyclopedias, that
> depends on the underlying ordering of the alphabet of symbols used to
> build the words. The lexicographical order is one way of formalizing
> word order given the order of the underlying symbols.
>
> The formal notion starts with a finite set A, often called the
> alphabet, which is totally ordered. That is, for any two symbols a and
> b in A that are not the same symbol, either a < b or b < a.
>
> The words of A are the finite sequences of symbols from A, including
> words of length 1 containing a single symbol, words of length 2 with 2
> symbols, and so on, even including the empty sequence varepsilon with no symbols
> at all. The lexicographical
> order on the set of all these finite words orders the words as
> follows:
>
> Given two different words of the same length, say a = a1a2...ak and b
> = b1b2...bk, the order of the two words depends on the alphabetic order of the symbols in the first place i where the two words differ
> (counting from the beginning of the words): a < b if and only if ai <
> bi in the underlying order of the alphabet A. If two words have
> different lengths, the usual lexicographical order pads the shorter
> one with "blanks" (a special symbol that is treated as smaller than
> every element of A) at the end until the words are the same length,
> and then the words are compared as in the previous case.

After this you can learn about Co-Lexicographical Order from the same Wikipedia page mentioned above. Above quoted part is taken directly from the *Motivation and Definition* titled part of the Wikipedia page mentioned above. Visit it once and you will have a better understanding of both.

You just need to find the Lexicographical and Co-Lexicographical position of **(i, j, k)** among all possible **(foo1, foo2, foo3)** in the array `A` of yours:

```
foo1 -> L possibilities: [Lower Bound x, Upper Bound x + L - 1]  
foo2 -> M possibilities: [Lower Bound y, Upper Bound y + M - 1]  
foo3 -> N possibilities: [Lower Bound z, Upper Bound z + N - 1]
```

Based on the this knowledge, you will get that:
1). Number of elements `A[foo1][foo2][foo3]` *(foo1, foo2, foo3)* present before element `A[i][j][k]` *(i, j, k)* in Row Major Order or Lexicographical Order are:
`[ (i - x)*M*N + (j - y)*N + (k - z) ]`

2). Number of elements `A[foo1][foo2][foo3]` *(foo1, foo2, foo3)* present before element `A[i][j][k]` *(i, j, k)* in Column Major Order or Co-lexicographical Order are:
`[ (i - x) + (j - y)*L + (k - z)*L*M ]`

Now, you can do the rest of your calculation where you bring in your `base` and `W` thing to get the final answer you need.